# High Charts PieChart How Can I show point value inside segment and label name outside

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Exactly as the title says.
https://jsfiddle.net/4wrLampu/5/

I have this pie chart with a simple series of data, and a central pie displaying total.

I want the data name and value to stay as is just outside the segment but I also want to display the percentage value of the segment in the center of the segment.

Is this possible with high charts, what would be the most straightforward route to achieving this?

For those who don't want to look at jsfiddle, this is the code for the current chart.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
$('#pieChart').highcharts({
   credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'pie',
        marginTop: 20,
            marginRight: 10,
            marginLeft: 10,
            marginBottom: 20,
        spacingTop: 0,
        spacingBottom: 0,
        spacingLeft: 0,
        spacingRight: 0,
    },
      plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                size:'100%',
                center: ['50%', '50%'],
                borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                 distance: 0,
                    color: '#333333',
                    formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: <br/>'+      this.point.y;
                        }
            },
            }
        },

    title: {
        text: 'Your Repayment'
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name:'Total',
        size: '39%',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            distance: -30,
            y: -50,
            color: '#ccc',
      style: {
        fontSize: "18px",
        fontFamily: "Arial, sans-serif",
        fontWeight: "normal"
      },
      labelFormatter:function () {  
   return '<span style="margin-top:-30px;">'+this.name+'<span>'+' $'+this.y; 
}
        },
        data:[{
            name: 'Total',
            color:'#B2B2B2',
            y:1309
        }]
    },
    {   type: 'pie',
         name: 'My Pie Chart',
        colorByPoint: true,
         size: '80%',
    innerSize: '50%',
        data:[{
            name: 'Value Name 1',
            color:'#72BB32',
            y: 984
        },{
            name:'Value Name 2',
            color:'#F1E52B',
            y: 250
        },{
            name:'Value Name 3',
            color:'#A67461',
            y: 75
        }]
    }],
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have two separate values for a single pie chart slice (a value outside the slice and a percentage inside), you'll need two different `series` objects in your chart definition.  Each one will have different `dataLabels`.

Basically, you'll want to add this extra object to the `series` array:

```
{
  type: 'pie',
  name: 'My Pie Chart',
  size: '90%',
  dataLabels: {
    distance: -50,
    formatter: function() {
      if (this.percentage != 0) return Math.round(this.percentage) + '%'
    }
  }
}
```

See jsfiddle for working version: https://jsfiddle.net/bb83f2by/

Comment: Thanks Dr Cool, in the jsfiddle the central value background color is gone. . When i add it the Central Value label dissapears.

Comment: Yeah, I fixed it.  There are 3 items in the ``series`` array.  The "Total" circle in the middle can't be first because it's gray color is being hidden by the other items.  Just move it to the second or third index of the array and it'll work.